# iterator successor

Tags: c++, boost, stl, iterator

I want to initialize an iterator (of arbitrary kind) with the successor of another iterator (of the same kind). The following code works with random access iterators, but it fails with forward or bidirectional iterators:

```
Iterator i = j + 1;
```

A simple workaround  is:

```
Iterator i = j;
++i;
```

But that does not work as the *init-stament* of a for loop. I could use a function template like the following:

```
template <typename Iterator>
Iterator succ(Iterator it)
{
    return ++it;
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
Iterator i = succ(j);
```

Is there anything like that in the STL or Boost, or is there an even better solution I am not aware of?

Comment: You say that `Iterator i = j; ++i;` isn't possible inside a `for` loop - can you expand on that?  It should work fine in a `for` loop.

Comment: @Michael: I meant the place `x` in `for (x; y; z)`, not inside the loop body itself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`next` in Boost.Utility](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#functions_next_prior). It also has `prior` for obtaining an iterator to a previous element.

Update:

C++11 introduced [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) and [`std::prev`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev).

Comment: for completeness, there is also `prev` :)

Comment: @Matthiew M.: I think you mean `prior`. It's in my link. Now I added a mention of it to my answer.

Comment: `next` is now part of C++11 http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next