# Assigning to an object

Tags: c++, coding-style, side-effects

Is there any reasonable explanation of following techinque:

```
//value HAS TO BE CHANGED those are requirements
int f(int value)
{
int tmp = value;//In order to not change "value" inside fnc - again requirements
//do something with tmp
return tmp;
}

int a = 0;
a = f(a);//here I assign to a anyway
```

instead of this:

```
void f(int& value)
{
//do something with value
}
```

or this:

```
int f(int& value)
{
//do something with value
return value;
}
```

and would you agree that first code snippet is (in general) an example of bad programming practice?

Comment: I can't see an obvious reason for the first case; value is local, the function can do with it as it wishes without affecting the caller...  But it's allowed and might make sense for some reasons.

Comment: What are you asking? The difference between the tree? Which one is preferable (*under what circumstances?*)? If any is "evil"?

Comment: This code makes no sense whatsoever. Did you mean to accept by reference in the first function too?

Comment: The first example is bad practice in the sense that `f()` is completely superfluous.

Comment: @Downvoters at least have a guts to explain why. What, is this question unclear or not useful?

Comment: @Oli: superfluous how? It returns a new value, which is assigned to `a` by the caller. All the stuff with `tmp` is superfluous though, but the function itself isn't, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a reason for the `tmp = value` bit since in the first version, the parameter isn't a reference, but I think it's often a good practice to take the parameter by value, and then return an updated copy, instead of taking and modifying references. Fewer side effects makes the code easier to reason about.

So I'd say the nicest version is this:

```
int f(int value)
{
  //do something with value
  return value;
}

int a = f(a);
```

I'm not sure why you insisted on making the parameter a reference in your third example.

Comment: thank you for your answer. That is a original example from my university. They want us to not change variable passed to a fnc (IT'S FORBIDDEN), create temporary and then assing this temporary to the same variable temporary is a copy of. That's why I'm asking this Q here. Is there ANY reasonable explanation for that, and is it consider to be a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

If you really do not want to change `value`, make it `const`. But honestly, I see no reason to do so.

Comment: that't the whole point. I do want to change value of variable lets call it a but not inside the function. Please don't ask me why. I'm asking this Q here for in my University they theach us to do exactly the way I've shown in first snippet and that's why this whole question.

Comment: @There: Have you asked your university tutor for the rationale?

Comment: @Oli I asked them (arround two weeks ago) but so far no answer has been given to me, so I've decided to ask this question here.

Comment: @There: Functions that change their arguments can be confusing and, from a functional programming perspective, are not very compositional (you cannot use a void function as a building block in an expression). [Sometimes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716337/), you really want to say `i + 1` instead of `++i`.

Answer (score 1):

If you needed the original value of `value` for reference. For example, if you wanted to do some operations on it and then compare to see if it was the same afterwards. And return the value.

Seems a little obscure, but it would make sense.

Comment: just this example I'm interested in. No comparison etc, etc. Just this example.

Comment: You have left out the 'do something with tmp'. That do something could involve operations that then require the original value as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

One reasonable explanation I can think of for the first version is that you can use the function even if you don't want to modify the parameter, but only return the result. I wouldn't agree that writing a function like that is bad programming practice.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what is desired by programmer precisely. For this use `a = f(a)`, I don't see a difference since the result will obviously be same. But considering in general, a use such as `a = f(a) + f(a)` would give a different result. So I can't say it's totally a bad programming practice.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you want to use the function. For example you can evaluate the first version of the function like so:

```
avariable = f(avalue)
```

Only `avariable` will change.

You can use the second version of the function like so:

```
 f(&avalue)
```

Only `avalue` will change.

You can use the last version of the function like so:

```
 avariable = f(&avalue)
```

Both `avariable` and a `avalue` will change.

They all have their uses. It depends on what you as the programmer need from them. Just ask yourself: Which variable(s) do you need returned modified by the function?

Comment: In both your and OP's first example, you could ignore the int temp = value and still have the not-avalue-changing part since it's by value.

Comment: @Rob you (in my example) have to pass value and assing to a value - the same obj is being assing to and passed as a argument in other words.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do My answer still holds true though. If that's all you want then you should of course use either the first or second version of the function.

Comment: @Rob so you're actually saying that creating temporary of A and then assinging this temporary to this same A is ok?

Comment: @There is nothing we can do Yes, it's perfectly valid although I think it's a waste of 8 bytes. Although I have to ask you, if all you're wondering about is the temporary value in the first example then why the rest of the question providing two different functions which are used for entirely different purposes?

Comment: @Rob I'm not saying if it's valid or not. What I'm asking is this: Is there any point in: 1. Creating variable of obj which was passed to a fnc as a argument when we now that we will reassing the result to the same variable. So it's going to be like the following. Variable A is passed to a fnc, then copy of this variable is created and then the copy is assign back again to A. Does it make any sense? And note that I'm not asking if that's valid code. I know it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

You could need the original value for some use, it depends on what you have to do. For instance, a temporary variable could be used to store one of the two parameters during "swap" (although there's a built-in swap function in the STD):

```
void swap(int& first, int& second) {
    int tmp = second;
    second = first;
    first = tmp;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, “for native types”? I believe `std::swap` works on any type that is copy-constructible and assignable, by doing exactly what you wrote for `int`.